# Get the value of has_many in rails error(no method error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When i execute the command to appear the column of user when have the many comments this error:

```
      <% post.comments.each do |comment|   %>
        <div id="comments" >
          <%= comment.user.email if comment.user.email != nil %>
               <%= comment.comment %>
        </div>
NoMethodError in Posts#index

Showing /Users/overallduka/Blog1/app/views/posts/index.html.erb where line #50 raised:

undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #50):
```

The comments model have belongs_to user and the user model have has_many comments, as right this, but i dont identifie the problem, i check and all my comments have user_id , please some solution please.

Comment: You mention that all your comments have their user_id defined, but are you sure they are all valid user ids? i.e. maybe a comment has a user_id for a user which no longer exists. Just one possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that at least one of the `comments` on your `post` object has a `nil` value for the `user` association. You're checking that `email` is not nil, but you're not checking whether `user` itself is nil (which is what is triggering the `NoMethodError`).

As a start, I would change this line:

```
<%= comment.user.email if comment.user.email != nil %>
```

to:

```
<%= comment.user && comment.user.email %>
```

This is a handy pattern in ruby which first checks that `comment.user` is defined, and if it is defined returns the second argument, i.e. `comment.user.email`. If `comment.user` is not defined (or `nil`, or `false`) then the second argument is not evaluated, and the return value is nil (so if no user is defined, then `comment.user.email` is never evaluated so you don't get an error).